# Trying to debug website project under local IIS vs2017

Tags: debugging, iis, visual-studio-2017, local

I have a website project the debugs in IIS Express. I have an error that only shows up in the production IIS environment. I've installed IIS and created a website who's virtual directory points to my dev website. It runs under IIS - port 7500. How do I now debug it through vs2017. The only debug options are IIS Express.

Thanks
Abbott

Comment: Do you mean that it has no local IIS option in your project property? Could you share the detailed error messages? Of course, if you want to debug your app with IIS Express, you could use the attach to process window and attach to the IIS proccess "w3wp.exe".

Comment: Would you please share the latest information about this issue? Actually if I enabled IIS under Turn Windows Features On or Off, I could find the local IIS option in my web project property.

Comment: I added my website as a virtual site in IIS management console with the port 7500 and start the site. I use the url localhost:7500 to start the site in my browser. You have to run VS as an administrator. I then attach-to-process under the debug tab and select w3wp.exe and your in business.

Comment: Do you mean that you could debug your app now?